# re.findall on each sentence of a list

Tags: python, regex, string, list, nltk

I have got a list of sentences:

```
[                              'home twn cafe nr link rd',  
                                'taj lands ends hotel..',  
            'SILVER PALACE705BPALI MALA ROADBANDRA WEST',  
     'turner rd lemon rd 4 fountain  pali rd junctio...',    
      ' FLAT 657 FLOOR AIR INDIA APTS 61B PALI HILL',  
                        'bungalow 9 Mt Mary Bandra West',  
     'shabbir apt charklie rajan rd abv icici ban...',  
                'st peters church backyard loun hill rd',  
                                       'Union Park Road ', 
                                 'Flat 32 Building No 8',  
                                       'mehboob studio',  
                                          'ONGC Colony',  
'Nargis Dutt Road Grand Canyon Building Appa']
```

I need to use re.findall to find all words with 'rd', and replace them with 'road'. I tried this :

```
data2 = [nltk.sent_tokenize(lines) for lines in data]  
c = [re.findall('nr',sent) for sent in data2]
```

and I got this error :

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

how do I use `re.findall` in an iterative statement? dunno how to convert to string.. plz help

Comment: If that's supposed to be a list of sentences, then why are you running a sentence splitter on it?

Comment: i'm a newbie , so i dont exactly know what to do.. the first statement was to tokenize each sentence so that it can be treated as an entity. second one is for iterating over each tokenized sentence.. please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a simple RegEx and list comprehension like this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"\brd\b")
print [pattern.sub("road", line) for line in data]
```

**Output**

```
['home twn cafe nr link road',
 'taj lands ends hotel..',
 'SILVER PALACE705BPALI MALA ROADBANDRA WEST',
 'turner road lemon road 4 fountain  pali road junctio...',
 ' FLAT 657 FLOOR AIR INDIA APTS 61B PALI HILL',
 'bungalow 9 Mt Mary Bandra West',
 'shabbir apt charklie rajan road abv icici ban...',
 'st peters church backyard loun hill road',
 'Union Park Road ',
 'Flat 32 Building No 8',
 'mehboob studio',
 'ONGC Colony',
 'Nargis Dutt Road Grand Canyon Building Appa']
```

Comment: hi , thnx it worked.. i need to understand the concepts of string , list conversions etc.. could u suggest some site? i have gone through nltk.org already..

Comment: @Sword Please have a look at [List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), [String Methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Comment: thanx bro.. i hope you guys understand that i'm new to nltk so my questions and approaches might be somewhat wrong. so i thank you for cooperating and supporting me :)

Comment: @fourtheye , what if i want to correct multiple words at once.. like opp,op with opposite , abv by above and so on.. ??

Comment: i've done it by overwriting data each tym. so in the end i'll have everything right..

Comment: check this out http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81330-single-pass-multiple-replace/